# How To Add Dash Between Controllers Name In Kohana?

Tags: routes, kohana, kohana-3

I'm working on authorization module for Kohana 3.1. In my module's *init.php*...

```
Route::set(

    'a11n',
    '<controller>',
    array(
        'controller' => 'signIn|signOut|signUp'
    )

);
```

I'm not 100% sure how use to Kohana's routing mechanism, but with this I'm trying to achieve that user can type "signIn", "signOut" or "signUp" to run controllers from my module. You see, I want have "portable" authorization system... so I can simply "copy-paste" right directory, enable the module and my site have authorization.

Keep in mind, with this route I don't want to anyhow change behavior of default routes. I don't know how correct my code is... but it works! I tested and I can get the same effect without using 3rd parameter too. What do I achieve with it now?

And now the question... How can I somehow set routes from module that by typing "sign-in" user run module "Controller_SignIn"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the routes to do that, something like this:

```
Route::set('SignIn', '/sign-in(/<action>)',
        array(
            'action' => 'index|action1',
            )
        )
        ->defaults(
                array(
                    'controller' => 'SignIn',
                    'action' => 'index',
                    )
                );

Route::set('SignOut', '/sign-out(/<action>)',
        array(
            'action' => 'index|action1',
            )
        )->defaults(
                array(
                    'controller' => 'SignOut',
                    'action' => 'index',
                    )
                );
```

or

```
Route::set('SignIn', '/sign-in/',
        array()
        )
        ->defaults(
                array(
                    'controller' => 'user',
                    'action' => 'login',
                    )
                );

Route::set('SignOut', '/sign-out/)',
        array()
        )->defaults(
                array(
                    'controller' => 'user',
                    'action' => 'logout',
                    )
                );
```

Comment: Using the routes is more maintainable, you don't need to touch the controller if you want to change the route again.

Comment: Imo, this way is better, see my comment on the other question.

Comment: @gimpe What the problem with routes in my example? You can change action name in `before()` method for your needs.

Comment: @biakaveron The Kohana process is to load index.php that loads bootstrap.php (where the routes are created) and at the end index.php will execute the right controller/action after resolving the uri. Modifying the action in a controller makes it harder to debug and maintain as you can't rely on the routes definition to predict the application behaviour.

Comment: I dont see any problems with debug. My route shows a controller name, and then I see a `before()` entry and know what method will be called. It has no hidden redirects, just a small dash replacement (like your route too). Anyway, @daGrevis can use this combination: `Route::set('SignIn', 'sign-in')->defaults(array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'signin'));` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question already has an answer marked as solution, but there is a cleaner/another way of doing it:

Create a new file in your application: `application/classes/request.php` and put the following code in that file:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
class Request extends Kohana_Request
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->action(str_replace('-', '', $this->action()));
        $this->controller(str_replace('-', '', $this->controller()));
        return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

Now you don't have to modify/pollute your bootstrap.php for every dashed/hyphenated url!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you create separated controllers for account actions? Create one controller (`Controller_Account` or something else) with actions you need:

```
class Controller_Account extends Controller_Template {

    public function action_signin() {...}

    public function action_signout() {...}

    public function action_signup() {...}

}
```

As you can see, action names are without dashes. You cant use them in method names. But here is a hack for it:

```
public function before()
{
    parent::before(); // dont forget this call!
    // remove dashes from current method name
    $this->request->action(str_replace('-', '', $this->request->action()));
}
```

And route:

```
Route::set(
       'a11n', 
       '<action>', 
       array('action' => array('sign-in|sign-up|sign-out'))
    )
    ->defaults(array('controller' => 'account'));
```

Of course, you can use both signin and sign-in names, just add non-dashed names to Route regex param:

```
Route::set(
       'a11n', 
       '<action>', 
       array('action' => array('sign-in|sign-up|sign-out|signin|signup|signout'))
    )
    ->defaults(array('controller' => 'account'));
```

Comment: Note that with this you'll end up with multiple url's for identical pages (/signin is the same as /sign-in). If you use the answer by gimpe, only /sign-in would work.

Comment: You can redirect from '/signin' to '/sign-in' in `before()`. Anyway, I dont understand, why do you like to create one controller for an action?